# QGIS 2.4 - Python 2.7 PyQT4.Qtcore.QStringList Import failed

Tags: qgis, import, pyqt

I receive an import error when trying to import QStringList from the QGIS Python console (or when loading a custom plugin).

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QStringList
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name QStringList
```

I receive no error when using the same import from an ipython console or executing a standalone python script.

Python 2.7.5+
[GCC 4.8.1]

Please advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't import QStringList in QGIS 2.x because we are using SIP bindings v2 which auto converts the types to Python types.

If you are buildling at a standalone app you should import `qgis.core` before import `PyQt4` because `PyQt4` will set the sip API to V1 before QGIS can set it to v2.

**Long story short:**

Do this:

```
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
```

Not this:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from qgis.core import *
```

Because:

QGIS sets the API version to 2 or else PyQt4 will set it to version 1. Once it's set it can't be changed.

Version 2 is heaps better so use that.

Answer (score 1):

Since I wasn't doing much 'exoticism' with that QStringList I tried to subsitute with a simple python List With Success.

`try:
    from PyQt4.QtCore import QStringList
except ImportError:
    QStringList = list`

then

```
ql = QStringList()
l = Global.getPG_connection().tableList     
for item in l:
    ql.append(item)
    #Pass the QStringList to the QInputDialog
    table, ok = QInputDialog.getItem(self, "something", "somewhere", ql )
```

allow proper construction of my QInputDialog.

Comment: That said, I still have no clue regarding that error import! I check for name collision within my code without finding any. Anybody?

Comment: See my answer to why and what you should do.