# QStringList() error in plugin of QGIS 2.10

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I have made a Dialog in PyQt for use it like a plugin under QGIS 2.10

The Dialog works fine like a standalone application, but if I try to call it like a QGIS plugin, I get this error:

**AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'QStringList'**

There are a similar question [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109577/qgis-2-4-python-2-7-pyqt4-qtcore-qstringlist-import-failed/109589#109589), but it doesn't work for  me.

The form is made with Qt Designer

This is a snippet of my Dialog:

```
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtSql

from Ui_BuscadorParcelas import Ui_BuscadorParcelas

# create the dialog for BuscadorParcelas
class BuscadorParcelasDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
    .......................
    def PrepararCuadros(self):
        self.consulta = QtSql.QSqlQuery(self.conexion)      
        if self.consulta:
            for i in range(self.numCamposLineEdit):
                cadenaConsulta = "SELECT DISTINCT "+self.campo[i]+" FROM crcc ORDER BY "+self.campo[i];
                self.consulta.exec_(cadenaConsulta)
                self.ListaValores = QtCore.QStringList()
         ...................................................
```

I need the QStringList() to set a QCompleter object

I complete the answer of Mathias Kuhn saying that if I get the values of the list from a database query, like my example, I need to prepend ***unicode*** for obtain a python list that QCompleter can use like argument (first line in the following code replace last line of first one)

```
self.ListaValores = []
while self.consulta.next():
    self.ListaValores.append(unicode(self.consulta.value(0)))
self.completer = QtGui.QCompleter(self.ListaValores, self)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QGIS updated to the SIP API V2 between 1.8 and 2.0.

See:
https://hub.qgis.org/wiki/17/Python_plugin_API_changes_from_18_to_20#Replace-QStringList-with-list

It will transparently convert some types (like QString or QList) between python and Qt types.

So you can just use a python list of str or unicode objects and pass it to the pyqgis and pyqt API wherever a QStringList is expected.

```
listaValores = [u'uno', u'dos', u'tres']
completer = QCompleter(listaValores)
```

Comment: I have followed your instructions but Completer complaints about the type

Comment: Well, I have made an example out, with a standalone QLineEdit, and it works! Complete accept a python list like argument. But inside QGIS doesn accept a python list like argument

Comment: Thank you. Now it works. I have made a small remark to your answer

Comment: I guess that applies if the values you get are not of type `str` or `unicode` (like integers, doubles...) then you will have to convert them so you get a QStringList instead of a QVariantList