# refreshLayerSymbology raster layer legend

Tags: raster, pyqgis, legend

When I modify raster colors with PyQGIS, the legend in the layout layer is not update (color and value). The function `refreshLayerSymbology()` in my code don't do the job.

[image]

I had try this :

```
# BBOX
extent = box
# acces données
provider = self.MNT.dataProvider()
stats = provider.bandStatistics(1, QgsRasterBandStats.All, extent, 0)

if (stats.minimumValue < 0):
    min = 0

else:
    min = stats.minimumValue
max = stats.maximumValue
range1 = max - min
add = range1 // 2
interval = min + add

colDic = {'red': '#ff0000', 'yellow': '#ffff00', 'blue': '#0000ff'}

valueList = [min, interval, max]

lst = [QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(valueList[0], QColor(colDic['blue'])),
       QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(valueList[1], QColor(colDic['yellow'])),
       QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(valueList[2], QColor(colDic['red']))]

myRasterShader = QgsRasterShader()
myColorRamp = QgsColorRampShader()

myColorRamp.setColorRampItemList(lst)
myColorRamp.setColorRampType(QgsColorRampShader.INTERPOLATED)
myRasterShader.setRasterShaderFunction(myColorRamp)

myPseudoRenderer = QgsSingleBandPseudoColorRenderer(self.MNT.dataProvider(),
                                                    self.MNT.type(),
                                                    myRasterShader)
# Add
self.MNT.setRenderer(myPseudoRenderer)

# Refresh the canvas and the legend
self.MNT.triggerRepaint()
#self.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
self.iface.legendInterface().refreshLayerSymbology(self.MNT)
```

However when I use the function `refreshLayerSymbology()` with grayscale color, the function work.

[image]

The code I used is :

```
myGrayRenderer = QgsSingleBandGrayRenderer(self.MNT.dataProvider(), 1)

self.MNT.setRenderer(myGrayRenderer)

renderer = self.MNT.renderer()
# acces données
provider = self.MNT.dataProvider()

layer_extent = self.MNT.extent()
uses_band = renderer.usesBands()

myType = renderer.dataType(uses_band[0])

stats = provider.bandStatistics(uses_band[0],
                                QgsRasterBandStats.All,
                                layer_extent,
                                0)

myEnhancement = QgsContrastEnhancement(myType)
contrast_enhancement = QgsContrastEnhancement.StretchToMinimumMaximum

myEnhancement.setContrastEnhancementAlgorithm(contrast_enhancement, True)
myEnhancement.setMinimumValue(stats.minimumValue)
myEnhancement.setMaximumValue(stats.maximumValue)

self.MNT.renderer().setContrastEnhancement(myEnhancement)

# Refresh the canvas and the legend
self.MNT.triggerRepaint()
self.iface.legendInterface().refreshLayerSymbology(self.MNT)
```

Comment: Which QGIS version and platform are you using?

Comment: I use QGIS V2.18.9 and python 2.7.4 on Windows 7 professionnel.

Comment: I do not understand why the function "refreshLayerSymbology" does not work. Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: Try looping through your layers and refresh their symbology: `for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():`; `qgis.utils.iface.legendInterface().refreshLayerSymbology(layer)`

Comment: Your solution don't work, i hope the problem come from the function "ColorRampItem" which need a "QString" in argument to specify the value. My actual problem is that i can't import "QString" from "PyQt4.QtCore" because my plugin import "PyQt4.QtCore'" before "qgis.core" as specify in [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109577/qgis-2-4-python-2-7-pyqt4-qtcore-qstringlist-import-failed/261784?noredirect=1#comment414724_261784).

Comment: Solved in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/313809/how-to-update-the-layer-tree-view-after-changing-the-color-ramp-in-pyqgis